# Is my code is failing because I adapted an intent to a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making a code where I'm implementing a login and a signUp with shared preferences but when i run the app in my cellphone the app doesn't start and crash.

The app should save a user and a password but it doesn't open, it just crash. I'm not sure if it is maybe something related with the thing that the code was originally an intend and tried to adjust it to fragment because i was using fragment.

PS: I'm new to Kotlin in android studio

```
class Login : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var fbinding: FragmentLoginBinding
    var txtUsu: EditText? = null
    var txtPass: EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        txtUsu = fbinding.etUsuarioL.findViewById(R.id.et_usuarioL)
        txtPass = fbinding.etContrasenaL.findViewById(R.id.et_contrasenaL)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        fbinding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        navLogin()
        return fbinding.root
    }

    fun login(view: View){
        var pref = this.activity?.getSharedPreferences(txtUsu?.text.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var pass = pref?.getString("Pass", "")
        if (pass == txtPass?.text.toString()){
            navLogin()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Error en las credenciales, intente de nuevo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            txtUsu?.setText("")
            txtPass?.setText("")
        }
    }

    private fun navLogin(){
        fbinding.btnInises.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(fbinding.root).navigate(R.id.action_login_to_menu2)
        }
    }

}
```

signUp.kt

```
class registro : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var fBinding: FragmentRegistroBinding
    var txtUsu: EditText? = null
    var txtPass: EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fBinding = FragmentRegistroBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        txtUsu = fBinding.etUsuarioR.findViewById(R.id.et_usuarioR)
        txtPass = fBinding.etContraseAR.findViewById(R.id.et_contraseñaR)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registro, container, false)
    }

    fun guardar(view: View){
        var pref = this.activity?.getSharedPreferences(txtUsu?.text.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var editor = pref?.edit()
        editor?.putString("pass", txtPass?.text.toString())
        Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        txtUsu?.setText("")
        txtPass?.setText("")
    }

    fun irLogin(){
        fBinding.btnAceptarR.setOnClickListener{
            Navigation.findNavController(fBinding.root).navigate(R.id.action_registro_to_login)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do post the stack trace of the error

Comment: You should NEVER store the username and password of a user.  People reuse passwords, and storing them means any malicious person or app that gains access to the phone can read his password.  In fact checking for badly designed code like this is likely to be one of the first things they do.  Instead, you should just save whatever cookie or token the website uses to authenticate future requests.

Comment: In fact your server shouldn't even be storing passwords in plain text.  It should store the salted and hashed version of the password.  Never store a password anywhere in plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just post code, also post the stack trace of the error.

Looking at your code, you are getting an exception due to using both `viewBinding` and simple layout based inflation. When using `viewBinding`, only 1 should be used. Either `viewBinding` or layout based inflation.

Another flag is you are using `findViewByID` with `viewBinding` which defeats the whole purpose of `viewBinding`.

Use this instead : ->

```kotlin
private lateinit var fBinding: FragmentRegistroBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    fBinding = FragmentRegistroBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    return fBinding.root
}

fun guardar(view: View){
    var pref = this.activity?.getSharedPreferences(fBinding.etUsuarioR.text.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var editor = pref?.edit()
    editor?.putString("pass", fBinding.etContraseAR.text.toString())
    Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    fBindinget.UsuarioR.setText("")
    fBinding.etContraseAR.setText("")
}

fun irLogin(){
    fBinding.btnAceptarR.setOnClickListener{
        Navigation.findNavController(fBinding.root).navigate(R.id.action_registro_to_login)
    }
}
```